# Copying from two sparsebundles is way too slow

Tags: catalina, usb, sparsebundle

I have a sparsbundle of 120 GB on a USB Key (USB 3, Kingston Data Traveller, 128 GB of space).

When I mount this sparsebundle, copying to it is extremely slow (we're talking 1 hour to copy 20 GB).

Is there an explanation as to why this is so slow? Can I do something about it?

Comment: What is the formatted as. why a sparse bundle not a plain filesystem.

Comment: The usb key is formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled). I opted for a sparsebundle and not plain filesystem because it is a backup for a sparsebundle that is on a mac.

Comment: Okay, USB 3, but how is it connected to what? Hardware specifications please.

Comment: A USB 3 Key, slotted into the USB port of a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

Comment: For best performance I'd format the **USB** _flash drive_ and the _.sparsebundle_ image as **APFS**, and see if things improve. I believe they will.

Comment: I have formatted both to APFS, but unfortunately it didn't help. Copying a 600 MB file from the SSD to the sparsebundle located on the usb drive takes 10 minutes...